# iOS 9 Hide status bar back button

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Is there any way to hide new status bar back button introduced in iOS9? I mean the button that is visible after launching application by [UIApplication openURL:].

Comment: I don't know why you're downvoted. Anyway, I'm not sure if fighting with new iOS features is the right thing to do. That button should rather stay there, also I doubt we have the possibility to hide it (can't find any reference).

Comment: After looking everywhere, I see no way to do this. I hope they add an ability to do this in the future. There are many cases where it would be appropriate to not show this back to app button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to hide "Back to Safari" from status bar in iOS9?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31247787/is-there-a-way-to-hide-back-to-safari-from-status-bar-in-ios9)

Answer (score 10):

Every time you use `[UIApplication openURL:]` iOS9 will generate the back button to the previous app. This feature is added to enable quick jumping from app to app. 


Apple made this private and *developers are not allowed to enable or disable this option*. Hopefully next versions of iOS will make this not so comfortable feature optional.

Comment: Usually is handy. But when I send a user of to authenticate via OAuth (Facebook, Safari, etc) and 15 seconds they're back, it seems a little bold to include the control in that case.

Comment: The OS has no idea that it was for an auth request unfortunately :/

Comment: @derrrick why not use a webview or safariviewcontroller for that auth request? just convenience or another reason?

Comment: @manmal safariviewcontroller is a really good option in some cases like you mentioned for auth but unfortunately it is only iOS9+ which can be worked around by webview though though all of these is a lot of work when you just want to open a link and I think that what question is about :)

Comment: @BagratKirakosian there are very-quick-to-add cocoapods though that are not harder to add than SFSafariViewController.

Comment: @manmal there definitely are some good cocoapods but I think question is a bit different